# Calling method inside prototype returns method is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a SliderControl for my website, I thought about making an object constructor so that I could re-use the code if I wanted to add more sliders. (I don't want to use jquery UI)

However I've run into an issue, when I `grab()` the slider, it tells me that `this.update(event)` is not a function. But `update(event)` is clearly defined and even defined before it's called.

```
var SliderControl = function (container, area, element) {
    'use strict';
    this.container = container;
    this.area = area;
    this.element = element;
    this.value = 0;
    this.active = false;
    this.actionWhenActive = false; // Ignore this 
};

SliderControl.prototype = {
    action: function () {
        'use strict';
    },
    width: function () {
        'use strict';
        var calcWidth = ((this.value * 100) + '%');
        this.element.width(calcWidth);
    },
    update: function (event) { // Apparently this doesn't exist
        'use strict';
        if (this.actionWhenActive === true) {
            this.action();
        }
        var direction, percent;
        direction = event.pageX - this.container.find(this.area).offset().left;
        percent = Math.min(Math.max(direction / this.container.find(this.area).width(), 0), 1.0);
        this.value = percent;
        this.width();
    },
    move: function (event) {
        'use strict';
        if (this.active === true) {
            this.update(event);
        }
    },
    grab: function (event) {
        'use strict';
        console.log('grabbed');
        event.preventDefault();
        this.active = true;
        this.update(event); // The error starts here
    },
    drop: function (event) {
        'use strict';
        console.log('dropped');
        if (this.active === true) {
            this.active = false;
            this.action();
        }
    },
    events: function () {
        'use strict';
        $(document).on('mousemove', this.move);
        $(document).on('mouseup', this.drop);
        this.area.on('mousedown', this.grab);
    }
};
```

If you need to test my code, I've included it in a fiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/a38trnk5/1/

Here's also working code (Placeholder code before I made the object constructor)

https://jsfiddle.net/zg3ezgnd/1/

Grab the black dot or click anywhere inside `.area` to move the slider.

Why is `this.update` not defined?

Comment: Since you called `update` from within the `grab` function which was called from an event the context of it's execution will be `window` and `window.update` is obviously not a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Rather, the mistaks starts in your `events` method, but manifests only in the event handler that is not a method.

Comment: @Bergi How so? I'm not getting any kinds of explenations here.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen: See the canonical question linked from the yellow box at the top of your post.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, It was a different question last time I checked. Thanks!

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Yeah, I reopened and reclosed to point to a better duplicate target, but you probably should read and understand [the old one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572) as well. Or the MDN page linked by Sukima.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, thanks. By the way, I googled and searched for this issue, but couldn't find anything. So sorry for the duplicate!

Comment: No need to be sorry - your question now serves as a signpost and should be found using the keywords you were using.